# Differences between storyboarding for game design vs. web design

Tags: gui, ui-design, user-experience, prototyping, storyboard

I'm looking to UX and storyboard out a web adventure game. The goal being to have an area to show what the UI/UX would look like (mockups), and ability to add dialog/blurbs to describe the screen.

I was thinking InVision, but that seems strictly for web development mockups. I could also simply draw them in Photoshop or on paper, but was looking more for something game design specific.

Are there significant differences between storyboarding for game design as opposed to web design? If so, how do UX or storyboarding tools cater to those differences?

Comment: Who's your intended audience? Is it something you want for yourself, publishers, investors, etc?

Comment: It's a tool I want for myself, but the game is for students ages 13-18

Comment: Straight up software recommendations are generally not deemed [on-topic for game dev SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Asking about process _might_ be on-topic enough & _might_ give you the info you need to select a good tool. If not, you might want to see your question is [on-topic for software rec SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) & try there.